# Troubleshooting engine damage after radiator hose failure

Tags: engine, damage, cooling

My mechanic replaced my radiator hoses.  2 weeks later, one came loose and the engine overheated and died.  It was put back on and 2 weeks after that, the hose began to leak. I brought it back and both hoses were replaced, said to be faulty.  An external compression test was performed but not internal compression test.  What does that mean and should I take the car to another mechanic for further testing or monitor the car for a while first?  It seems to rev higher upon acceleration, to 3RPMs but I have not had the car back for more than a day.

Comment: I'd try a different mechanic, hoses coming loose and/or bursting soon after being replaced could be a sign of poor workmanship.

Comment: Welcome to the site. More specific information about the car (make/model/engine) would be helpful. Also, which question are you seeking an answer; "*what does that mean*" or "*should I take the car to another mechanic*"? The later will likely result in lots of opinions.

Comment: What makes you think there is anything wrong with the car?

Comment: details:  this is a Subaru Forester 2010 2.5 4 cylinder

Comment: It runs fine, went 500 mi over the weekend, just getting higher rpms than usual at acceleration and on inclines... up to 4 at times, not in red zone.

Comment: The question is should I wait for symptoms with an incident like that? I'd like to not wait and trouble shoot since it was a result of poor workmanship.  Feeling better after a good long test drive. Thanks for responding.  Always grateful for advice as a novice.

Comment: Higher RPMs on acceleration and inclines would suggest you may have an issue with a worn on glazed clutch.

Answer (score 0):

leak test is the system pressure and head gasket,

change the thermastate 20$. get some bug remover on the rad and gentle wash it with a hose from under the bonnet side.

check electric radiator fan switch or sensor needs replacing.

make sure all air is bled from the system when refilled and open the heater controls to hot as well. good luck.

Comment: fan is fused so check that.

Comment: How does this diagnose engine damage?

Answer (score 0):

Do a compression and leak down test of your cooling system to see if the head gasket has failed. There could be more catastrophic damage also, like warped head!!!